# Adding a space between two linked labels

Tags: php

This might be the silliest question ever. But how do I get to put a space between the Edit and the Delete labels?

```
echo "  <a href=\"update.php?id=" . $id . "\"> Edit </a>";      
echo "  <a href=\"confirm.php?id=" . $id . "\"> Delete </a>";
```

I tried putting `echo " ";` in between but doesn't work. The underline is straight from Edit to Delete as if they are the same label!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to insert a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) between those :

```
echo "  <a href=\"update.php?id=" . $id . "\"> Edit </a>";      
echo ' &nbsp; ';
echo "  <a href=\"confirm.php?id=" . $id . "\"> Delete </a>";
```

Seems to help, here.

But, as an end-user, I tend to prefer having a dash between that kind of links :

```
echo "  <a href=\"update.php?id=" . $id . "\"> Edit </a>";      
echo ' - ';
echo "  <a href=\"confirm.php?id=" . $id . "\"> Delete </a>";
```

I just find it more easy to read and see there are actually two separate links.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, given your current code, is probably:

```
echo "  <a href=\"update.php?id=" . $id . "\">Edit</a> <a href=\"confirm.php?id=" . $id . "\">Delete</a>";
```

Failing that, I'd personally use the following

CSS:

```
ul {display: block; }

ul li {display: inline; margin: 0 0.5em; border-left: 1px solid #000; }

ul li:first-child {border-left: 0 none transparent; }
```

PHP

```
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li><a href=\"update.php?id=" . $id . "\">Edit</a></li>";      
echo "<li><a href=\"confirm.php?id=" . $id . "\">Delete</a></li>";
echo "</ul>";
```

Incidentally the problem with your code is that, in html, all white-space (outside of `<pre>` tags or `&nbsp;`) is collapsed down to a single space. So the underline of the `a` element extends into the spaces (as you've coded them, hence my first suggestion) enclosed within the link, and as any spaces between the closing of one `a` and the opening of the next is then collapsed into a single-space the underline does, indeed, run from one `a` up to the border of the `next` and, without trying to check, might even *overlap* each other, since that white-space is enclosed within the links.

...I might have to re-write that explanation a bit. =/ Hopefully it's useful to you, though. Anyway, that's why I initially removed the white-space from the links, and put it *between* the links instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. I learned a lot. I wish I could make your answer best too. Can't upvote as I am not reistered. :(

Comment: No worries; I'm glad to have helped. I'd certainly suggest registering, though, but I am, of course, clearly biased... =)

Answer (score 0):

remove the space between > and Edit, as well as the one between Edit and <.

Do the same for Delete.

The issue is that spaces are trimmed out of HTML, so that " " and "     " are treated the same.  When you have a space inside the  tag it's underlining that space, then the space outside the  tag is ignored (Because it is trimmed out).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
echo '&nbsp;'
```

between your two echo.